# Unable to include library in make file

Tags: c++, c, linux, makefile

I have the following 3 makefiles which have been generated by some other programmer. I have included my code in between which I have marked with a begin and end. The code intends to include the libspatial index library. The other programmer has the hierarchy root directory---->tools--->r

MakeFile1 corresponds to r, MakeFile2 corresponds to tools and MakeFile3 corresponds to root

Now when I include the library I get the error that

```
make all 
make: *** No rule to make target `bin//home/NP/rtree/spatialindex-src-1.8.0/src/storagemanager/DiskStorageManager.cc', needed by `bin/rdf3xload'.  Stop.
```

I am unable to understand as to what mistake did I make. Can someone be kind enough to help me out.

**MakeFile 1**

```
src_tools_r:=               \
    tools/r/r.cpp       \
    tools/r/Sorter.cpp      \
    tools/r/StringLookup.cpp    \
    tools/r/TempFile.cpp      \
    /home/NP/rtree/spatialindex-src-1.8.0/src/storagemanager/DiskStorageManager.cc

#Code which I wrote in order to include my library --begin
# for CS machines
COURSE_DIR = /home/NP/rtree/spatialindex-src-1.8.0/.libs
LIB_DIR     = /usr/local/lib

CPPFLAGS        = -I. \
                  -I$(COURSE_DIR)

LDFLAGS         = -L. \
                  -L$(COURSE_DIR) \
                  -R $(LIB_DIR):$(COURSE_DIR)

LDLIBS          = -lspatialindex
#Code which I wrote in order to include my library --end    

$(PREFIX)r$(EXEEXT): $(addprefix $(PREFIX),$(src_tools_r:.cpp=$(OBJEXT)) $(src_infra:.cpp=$(OBJEXT)) $(src_rts:.cpp=$(OBJEXT)) $(src_cts:.cpp=$(OBJEXT)))
    $(buildexe)
```

**MakeFile2**

```
include tools/r/MakeFile1

src_tools:=             \
    $(src_tools_r)      \

#Code which I wrote in order to include my library --begin
# for CS machines
COURSE_DIR = /home/NP/rtree/spatialindex-src-1.8.0/.libs
LIB_DIR     = /usr/local/lib

CPPFLAGS        = -I. \
                  -I$(COURSE_DIR)

LDFLAGS         = -L. \
                  -L$(COURSE_DIR) \
                  -R $(LIB_DIR):$(COURSE_DIR)

LDLIBS          = -lspatialindex
#Code which I wrote in order to include my library --end
```

**MakeFile3

```
# Include platform dependent makefiles
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
include Makefile.nt
else
include Makefile.unix
endif

PREFIX:=bin/

#############################################################################
# Default target
all: $(PREFIX)rd$(EXEEXT) $(PREFIX)r$(EXEEXT) $(PREFIX)rq$(EXEEXT) $(PREFIX)ru$(EXEEXT) $(PREFIX)re$(EXEEXT) $(PREFIX)ro$(EXEEXT)

#############################################################################
# Collect all sources


ifeq ($(LINEEDITOR),1)
src_lineeditor:=lineeditor/LineInput.cpp lineeditor/LineEditor.cpp lineeditor/Terminal.cpp lineeditor/Display.cpp lineeditor/Buffer.cpp
endif

include tools/Make2


source:=$(src_cts) $(src_infra) $(src_rts) $(src_tools) $(src_lineeditor)

#############################################################################
# Dependencies

generatedependencies=$(call nativefile,$(PREFIX)makeutil/getdep) -o$(basename $@).d $(IFLAGS) $< $(basename $@)$(OBJEXT) $(genheaders) $(GENERATED-$<)

ifneq ($(IGNORE_DEPENDENCIES),1)
-include $(addprefix $(PREFIX),$(source:.cpp=.d)) $(addsuffix .d,$(basename $(wildcard $(generatedsource))))
endif

#############################################################################
# Compiling

#Code which I wrote in order to include my library --begin
# for CS machines
COURSE_DIR = /home/NP/rtree/spatialindex-src-1.8.0/.libs
LIB_DIR     = /usr/local/lib

CPPFLAGS        = -I. \
                  -I$(COURSE_DIR)

LDFLAGS         = -L. \
                  -L$(COURSE_DIR) \
                  -R $(LIB_DIR):$(COURSE_DIR)

LDLIBS          = -lspatialindex



compile=$(CXX) -c $(TARGET)$(call nativefile,$@) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS-$(firstword $(subst /, ,$<))) $(IFLAGS) $(IFLAGS-$(firstword $(subst /, ,$<))) $(call nativefile,$<)

$(PREFIX)%$(OBJEXT): %.cpp $(PREFIX)makeutil/getdep$(EXEEXT)
    $(checkdir)
    $(generatedependencies)
    $(compile)

#############################################################################
# Cleanup

clean:
    find bin -name '*.d' -delete -o -name '*.o' -delete -o '(' -perm -u=x '!' -type d ')' -delete

#############################################################################
# Executable

$(PREFIX)query: $(addprefix $(PREFIX),$(source:.cpp=$(OBJEXT)))

#Code which I wrote in order to include my library --end
```

Comment: Try renaming `DiskStorageManager.cc` to `DiskStorageManager.cpp`, methinks your makefile expects a `.cpp` suffix.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for replying..now it is unable to find DiskStorageManager.o Also DiskStorageManager.cpp does not contain "main"...so why should I generate a .o file for it...

Comment: @DanielFischer Also when I put in "O_FILES         = $(SRC_FILES:%.cc=%.o) ". It says missing seperator.

Comment: Aha, some kind of progress. I suspect it doesn't find the `.o` file because it's not where make looks for it due to the different path. But to solve that, you need somebody who speaks make (better than I do).

Comment: @DanielFischer Ya..I hope I find an answer to my question..I have been  struggling with this question...anyways thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: I hope you get a good answer, wish I could have helped.

Comment: I suggest using `remake -x` it helps a lot debugging `Makefile`-s issues.

Comment: `DiskStorageManager.cc` is your code? What are you trying to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

If this is an independent library, it should have its own Makefile and should build alone as well.

If you want to integrate your source into the main build process, you must conform to their structure.

You have

- different c++ source suffix `.cc` vs `.cpp`
  This is easily resolvable by renaming your source files to `.cpp`.
- absolute path `/home/NP/rtree/...` vs relative path `tools/r/...`
  This would involve moving the entire tree into the main build tree, because the rules expect the directories to be accessible from there.

But I think the best is to have a library Makefile and integrate that into the main build.

Unfortunately, there is no easy answer like change variable X and move line Y. I recommend, sit down with your colleague and resolve this Makefile issue together.